# GWT / GWTBootstrap3 Extending Tooltip: Exception with addHandler in C'tor

Tags: gwtbootstrap3

I created the following class as an extension of gwtbootstrap3 Tooltip. There are at least 2 reasons why I want to derive the gwtbootstrap3 Tooltip class:

1.) Add a onWindowClosing Handler when the tooltip is shown so I can hide() the tooltip when the user leaves the page (this is - as far as I understand - a feature which is also not supported in Bootstrap, is it?)

2.)  I want to prevent Tooltips from being shown when the page is displayed on iPads or iPhones as they behave strange when tooltips are involved (first tip shows the tooltip , the second tip executes the button, which is not exactly what the user expects)

Please note that the class given below is still not finished ... but already at this stage I get an exception when adding a handler.
Please also note that it throws an exception no matter what type of Handler (ShowHandler, ShownHandler, etc.) I add.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
    package com.mypackage.client.widgets.featureWidgets;
    import org.gwtbootstrap3.client.shared.event.ShowEvent;
    import org.gwtbootstrap3.client.shared.event.ShowHandler;
    import org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.constants.Trigger;

    import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.ClosingEvent;

    public class Tooltip extends org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Tooltip {

        private boolean isMobile;
        private HandlerRegistration windowClosingHandlerRegistration;
        private final Tooltip tooltip;

        public Tooltip() {
            super();
            tooltip = this;

            this.addShowHandler(new ShowHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(final ShowEvent showEvent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (windowClosingHandlerRegistration == null) {
                        windowClosingHandlerRegistration = Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onWindowClosing(final ClosingEvent arg0) {
                                tooltip.hide();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
        }


    }


    When I create a instance of this tooltip using the following:

    [...]
        <b:ButtonToolBar ui:field="itemButtonToolBar" addStyleNames="hiddenPrint">
        <b:ButtonGroup>

            <a:Tooltip title="{msgs.buttomTitleAddItem}" container="body">
                <b:Button ui:field="addItemButton" icon="PLUS"/>
            </a:Tooltip>                                        
    [...]
```

I get the following exception when trying to add the Handler, why?

```
    SEVERE: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'addHandler_11_g$' of undefinedcom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'addHandler_11_g$' of undefined
        at Unknown.addShowHandler_2_g$(meetingApp-0.js@26:57195)
        at Unknown.Tooltip_6_g$(meetingApp-0.js@8:57685)
        at Unknown.build_f_Tooltip2_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@55:31606)
        at Unknown.get_f_Tooltip2_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@15:31831)
        at Unknown.build_f_ButtonGroup1_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@38:31524)
        at Unknown.get_f_ButtonGroup1_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@15:31791)
        at Unknown.build_itemButtonToolBar_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@41:31696)
        at Unknown.get_itemButtonToolBar_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@15:31876)
        at Unknown.createAndBindUi_58_g$(meetingApp-0.js@91:31437)
        at Unknown.createAndBindUi_59_g$(meetingApp-0.js@15:31441)
        at Unknown.ItemButtonGroup_2_g$(meetingApp-0.js@56:30733)
        at Unknown.$init_589_g$(meetingApp-0.js@31:37722)
        at Unknown.SummaryWidget_1_g$(meetingApp-0.js@8:37686)
        at Unknown.loadSummaryWidget_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@26:4991)
        at Unknown.setSummary_1_g$(meetingApp-0.js@10:5028)
        at Unknown.onSuccess_8_g$(meetingApp-0.js@21:3312)
        at Unknown.onSuccess_9_g$(meetingApp-0.js@8:3317)
        at Unknown.onResponseReceived_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@26:156917)
        at Unknown.fireOnResponseReceived_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@17:129224)
        at Unknown.onReadyStateChange_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@28:129532)
        at Unknown.<anonymous>(meetingApp-0.js@18:172082)
        at Unknown.apply_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@28:104636)
        at Unknown.entry0_0_g$(meetingApp-0.js@16:104692)
        at Unknown.<anonymous>(meetingApp-0.js@14:104672)
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I use gwtbootstrap3 v0.9.2 and I believe it's the same version as you use as I got the same error for your code.

A Tooltip needs a Widget to operate on (in your case the Button is a Tooltip's widget). Tooltip uses it's widget to do all events handling - see [source code](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/blob/0.9.2/gwtbootstrap3/src/main/java/org/gwtbootstrap3/client/ui/Tooltip.java) for `addShowHandler` for example.

Now you need to understand how the whole structure is built:

- first the Tooltip is created (wit no widget set)
- then the Button is created
- Tooltip's `setWidget` method is called to set the button as a widget

So when you use `addShowHandler` method in your constructor, you actually call `widget.addHandler` while widget is null.

You can check it by `Window.alert(tooltip.getWidget() == null ? "null" : tooltip.getWidget().toString());`

---

There are few ways to make it work (the later the better):

1. wait for DOM structure to be built by scheduling a deferred command (if you are sure that the widget will be eventually set):

   ```
   Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
       @Override
       public void execute() {
           // set up events handling
       }
   });
   ```
2. override `setWidget` method (note thet there are two methods: `setWidget(Widget w)` and `setWidget(IsWidget w)`):

   ```
   @Override
   public void setWidget(Widget w) {
       super.setWidget(w);
       // set up events handling
   }
   ```
3. you don't need to `addWindowClosingHandler` in the `showEvent` handler, you can do it directly in the constructor:

   ```
   public class Tooltip extends org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Tooltip {

       private boolean isMobile;
       private final Tooltip tooltip;

       public Tooltip() {
           super();
           tooltip = this;

           Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
               @Override
               public void onWindowClosing(final ClosingEvent arg0) {
                   tooltip.hide();
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your good explanation and your help. You are my hero!